# Unlimited field collection pagination in node edit page

Tags: 7, nodes, paging

In my node I have a field collection which is set to unlimited.
How to enable pagination for node edit page, where all items from that field collection are displayed?
For display there are couple possibilities - pagination modules, views etc. but how to do it for node edit page?

Comment: As far as I know no one did it. But I'll be happy if someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: @Molot I am not competing to you... ;)  dmk, you may use fieldgroup tabs and may manually add the new fields into new tabs. This is the worst case I can think of right now.

Comment: @AnAnD well, tabs are no pagination, but they can be good enough replacement. But as far as I understood (I never needed to actually use tabs with field groups) one fieldgroup can be one tab, so this does not help with many elements in one group? And you need to set it up on content type administration page? So if I'm right (hope I'm not) this will hardly help OP.

Comment: dmk, this was the worst case like I mentioned... I'll surely comment if I think of something much better...

Comment: @AnAnD Yes, I'm using fieldgroup tabs, but Mołot said everything about them :) They are some kind of help but I have to load all elements in them after all.

Comment: I have the same requirement for an entity reference field with over 10 000 values. It is impossible to load the node edit page with that many values unfortunately. Found this but it only does display https://drupal.org/project/cck_pager . Or this one, but it does not seem too scalable https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget

Comment: This is a fair question and there seems to be little or no information on how to properly go about it.  Fields with multiple values can be difficult to manage when they have hundreds or thousands of values, if at all possible.  cck_pager module mentioned by @giorgio79 doesn't have a stable release for Drupal 7 and doesn't seem to do the right thing either.

Comment: @dmk small sugestion. Do not use this edit field in the normal edit form but but a modal colorbox link on this place. In this colorbox you put a view the way you want (include a search box) as long list are not so nice for the user :-). Let the user select the item. Go on to a webform and then user a rule to update your object.

Answer (score 0):

A great solution to your problem would be to use the [EmbeddedViewField](https://www.drupal.org/project/embeddedviewfield) module. It fixes your problem, as mentioned in the module's project page:

> EmbeddedViewField is a module that will allow you to render a view as
>   any other field.
>
> It is based on keithm's ViewField module, except that it will always
>   render the view, regardless of whether the user is editing or
>   displaying the entity that has the EmbeddedViewField. The view used
>   for displaying is controlled by the default value set for the view.

Comment: This is good, almost there. But how do I keep the 'add another' field collection functionality?